# What is wrong with this Swift TimeZone for abbreviation for a date in another timezone assumption?

Tags: swift, date, timezone, timezone-offset

In an Xcode playground with the following Swift code, I get the commented output. Given a MST TimeZone object and a date that would be in the MDT TimeZone for this MST TimeZone, I do not receive the expected MDT TimeZone abbreviation output. What am I not understanding about this function, and how do I get the desired output of figuring out which of the two possible timezones a given date is in given the current example MST timezone?

```
// Daylight saving time (MDT) 2021 in Colorado began at 2:00 AM on Sunday, March 14
let mstDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 636327068) // "Mar 1, 2021 at 2:31 PM"
let mdtDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 637709468) // "Mar 17, 2021 at 3:31 PM"
let mstTimeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "MST")!
let mdtTimeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "MDT")!

mstTimeZone.abbreviation(for: mstDate) // expected MST, got MST
mstTimeZone.abbreviation(for: mdtDate) // expected MDT, got *****MST*****?

mdtTimeZone.abbreviation(for: mstDate) // expected MST, got MST
mdtTimeZone.abbreviation(for: mdtDate) // expected MDT, got MDT
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not rely on timezone abbreviations. MST means "Mountain Standard Time" but it is being interpreted as Phoenix, Arizona ("America/Phoenix") instead of Denver, Colorado ("America/Denver"). You should always use timezone identifiers instead of abbreviations which are ambiguous. The timezone identifier doesn't change based on a date. What you need is to check if it is daylight saving or not for the desired date/timezone and get a timezone localized name based on it:

```
extension TimeZone {
    static let denverCO = Self(identifier: "America/Denver")!
    func localizedName(for date: Date) -> String { localizedName(for: isDaylightSavingTime(for: date) ? .daylightSaving : .standard, locale: .current) ?? "" }
    func localizedNameShort(for date: Date) -> String { localizedName(for: isDaylightSavingTime(for: date) ? .shortDaylightSaving : .shortStandard, locale: .current) ?? "" }
}
```

---

```
let mst = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 636327068) // "Mar 1, 2021 at 2:31 PM"
let mdt = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 637709468) // "Mar 17, 2021 at 3:31 PM"
```

---

```
TimeZone.denverCO.localizedName(for: mst)  // "Mountain Standard Time"
TimeZone.denverCO.localizedName(for: mdt)  // "Mountain Daylight Time"

TimeZone.denverCO.localizedNameShort(for: mst)  // "MST"
TimeZone.denverCO.localizedNameShort(for: mdt)  // "MDT"
```

Comment: Timezone identifiers vs abbreviations didn't matter in this case, but through your answer I discovered the problem. So, Phoenix currently observes Mountain Standard Time (MST) all year. DST is no longer in use. Therefore `TimeZone(identifier: "America/Phoenix").isDaylightSavingTime(for: anyDateEver)` will always return false. This is also provable through your example code testing with the "America/Phoenix" (MST) timezone.

Comment: That’s why I have edited my answer. You can have different daylight savings behavior in the same timezone abbreviation. As I said you should be specific about which city you are talking about.

Comment: You are correct. Let me rephrase - in my particular example code, initializing my timezones with an abbreviation or an identifier didn't matter because they yield the same output as of right now, hence some of my initial confusion around abbreviations vs identifiers. That being said, I definitely understand why identifiers should always be used over abbreviations now. Thanks.