# Time zone in Date object Swift

Tags: ios, swift, date

I am trying to get a date object for the next day at midnight PST, but am struggling to find a way to make sure the time zone is right. This code will return a date object for midnight the next day, but not in PST, how can I fix this? I am not looking for a formatted string.

```
func getTomorrowMidnightPST() -> Date {
        let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Date())!
        let cal = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        return cal.startOfDay(for: date)
    }
```

Comment: Date holds no time zone so you can’t do this

Comment: The reason you think it can work like this is because Apple made `Date`s convert to a human-readable format when printed to the console. When a date gets printed, it gets converted to a string using a `DateFormatter` instance where the `timeZone` for that `DateFormatter` is GMT.

Answer (score 1):

`Date` is an instant in time independent of time zone. One instant (same `Date` instance) is represented differently in different time zones.

What you want instead is

1. set the calendar to the timeZone to what you desire.
2. ask it to compute that instant in time that will be start of tomorrow for that calendar.

Example -

```
var calender = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let tzPST = TimeZone(identifier: "America/Los_Angeles")! // Force cast tested for hard-coded value only
calender.timeZone = tzPST
if let tomorrow = calender.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Date()) {
    let tomorrowMidnightInPST = calender.startOfDay(for: tomorrow)
}
```

Remember that this `Date` instant still does NOT hold any time zone value with itself. Only calendar knows the time zone information.

Comment: You are using an abbreviation "PST" not an identifier. Note that there might be different daylight savings for the same abbreviation. You should always use the identifier. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66714163/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks a lot for clarifying this. I have updated the answer to use identifier instead of abbreviation.